# Snackbar and FloatingActionButton bug

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-design-library, floating-action-button

I have a FAB button in a `Coordinator Layout`, and I have set snackbars to pop up in the `Coordinator Layout`. However if a snackbar is visible and I execute an action that triggers another snackbar while the first one is still visible, the FAB button glitches and falls behind the snackbar. Instead of moving with the snackbar.

I have the `Coordinator Layout` within a `Relative Layout` though with an `adview` below the `Coordinator Layout`.

This is the `layout.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/circle2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/container2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:background="#FFF3E0"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <SurfaceView
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/circle"
            layout="@layout/periodictablelayout" />


        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_default"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"

            />
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/periodbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/container2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_view_comfy_white_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:layout_behavior="ibochemistry.titomo.timetoolay.google.com.ibchemistry.ScrollAwareFABBehaviour" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom" />
</RelativeLayout>
<!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
    android:name="ibo.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"

    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Comment: any luck ? I have the same bug myself

Answer (score 2):

How about moving the FAB up with the snackBar. I guess that will fix your problem. Whenever a snackBar is shown do this ,

```
SnackbarManager.show(
Snackbar.with(getApplicationContext()) // context
    .text("This will do something when dismissed") // text to display
    .eventListener(new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(Snackbar snackbar) {
            myFloatingActionButton.moveUp(snackbar.getHeight());
        }
        @Override
        public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("Snackbar shown. Width: %d Height: %d Offset: %d",
                    snackbar.getWidth(), snackbar.getHeight(),
                    snackbar.getOffset()));
        }
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(Snackbar snackbar) {
            myFloatingActionButton.moveDown(snackbar.getHeight());
        }
        @Override
        public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar) {
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("Snackbar dismissed. Width: %d Height: %d Offset: %d",
                                snackbar.getWidth(), snackbar.getHeight(),
                                snackbar.getOffset()));
        }
    }) // Snackbar's EventListener
, this); // activity where it is displayed
```

Let me know if it works for you...

Comment: This is just animating indepenently of the snackbar. What happens when the snackbar dissapears? I'll have to reanimate it back to its position.

This isn't going to look right when an old device glitches on the animation, and the snackbar overlaps the FAB or the FAB animated before the snackbar appears.

Comment: Yup you can bring it back in one line as above...But now do you want to animate the view or not? Check out my edited answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use,
here **view** - fabView

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Hello Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

this will show fab above snackbar

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in support lib 23.1.0 , just update your dependencies and it will fix it.